# mySQL + Facebook FQL queries make my page really slow. How to improve performance?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have many fan pages that I admin in Facebook and I made a little script to let me see how many fans they have. I have saved the pages (page_name + page_id ) I want in a mySQL database.  
The script makes a FQL query and prints how many fans every page has.

The problem is that when I added the FQL query, the page became kind of slow. I guess if I add other FQL queries it will become really slow to load.

My question is: What are some methods to use so my page will be loaded as fast as possible?

I thought of having the fans and other data saved in DB. But that means I will not have real time numbers.

Thank you.

```
$my_pages = mysql_query("SELECT page_name, page_id FROM pages WHERE user = '".$my_id."' ");

while($page_name = mysql_fetch_assoc($my_pages)) { 
    $fan_count = $facebook->api("/fql", array("q" => "SELECT fan_count FROM page WHERE page_id = '".$page_name['page_id']."'"));
      echo $page_name['page_name'].'-'.$fan_count['data'][0]['fan_count'], '<br />';

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll be much better to get all pages ids from DB, then issue single call to Graph API and just iterate over results.

```
$my_pages = mysql_query("SELECT page_name, page_id FROM pages WHERE user = '{$my_id}';");

$pages = array();
while($page = mysql_fetch_assoc($my_pages)) {
  $pages[] = $page['page_id'];
}
$pagesIds = implode(',', $pages);
$pagesFanCounts = $facebook->api("/fql", array(
  "q" => "SELECT page_id, name, fan_count FROM page WHERE page_id IN ({$pagesIds})"
));

foreach ($pagesFanCounts['data'] as $page){
  echo "{$page['name']} - {$page['fan_count']}", '<br />';
}
```

BTW, Never but never do calls to external services like this in a loop with unknown number of iterations and for sure not while having open connection to DB (this may slow down not only the single user result but may have impact on other visitors/application users)!

P.S.
You can read some stuff on FQL performance from removed and outdated (FQL stuff still conceptually correct) [Performance Guide](http://web.archive.org/web/20101205173437/http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/performance) (web.archive.org)

Comment: Thank you for this answer. So the difference between mine and yours way (yours is better for sure)is that you save the ids gotten from the DB in an array so you leave the DB "outside of the game right"?

Comment: And another one, what if I create a background script using cron jobs that checks and save in DB the fan count every 2-3 minutes for every page? Will this increase the speed if I get the data only from my DB?

Comment: @Kaoukkos, the difference is that code I've provided doing single call to Graph API vs call for every page (if user have 12 pages it's saves you 11 extra calls with all the networking overhead). For sure querying for many pages may be slower that for one, but it's be blazing fast compared to separate calls for every page).

Comment: @Kaoukkos, while you can create cron script it may be unnecessary (remember that you'll have to take care about `access_token` for user in your cronjob). My personal preference that kind of tasks is client-side unless you need those counts/numbers on the backend (actually even if you need 'em on backend, you may do that user is requesting that information on client-side from Graph API and giving it back to you).

Comment: Now I get the `WHERE page_id IN ({$pagesIds})`. Thank you very much my friend. I have accepted your answer!